# Vertically Distribute Two Horizontal Button Rows

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, interface-builder, uistackview

I'm trying to dynamically distribute two horizontal rows of buttons vertically in IB, `XCode 10.2.1`. Current efforts have produced this:
[[image: Storyboard for button rows [][1][1]]
The two rows can be distributed with the spacing values in the vertical stack, but I want it to dynamically vertically distribute depending on how much vertical space is available.

**Details:**
The two `UIStackViews` are embedded in a vertical `UIStackView`. As an attempt to get it to work, I've also embedded the vertical `UIStackView` in a `UIView` that is resized to the available space at the bottom of this screenshot (called "`UIStackView`", you can see it as the larger rectangle between Album Title and the bottom). None of the Distribution options in the vertical `UIStackView` have any effect on distributing the two horizontal rows.

Am I missing a constraint? My last resort is to programmatically adjust the spacing in the vertical stack depending on the size of the screen.

Also, not listed below: the top of the vertical `UIStackView` is not pinned to the top of the `UIView` - when I do this, I get one row way at the top, and one row at the bottom, when I use "equal spacing." When in this situation but choose "fill equally", the two rows are very near each other near the bottom, and the "Album Title" gets pulled way down to meet it (what's the best way to keep the Album Title where it is, BTW?). Perhaps the answer really lies in this situation, but with different constraints...

Here is the structure and constraints (top row and bottom row have the same kind of restraints).:
[image]
[image]

and here are the constraints for the encompassing UIView ("Stack View"):
[image]

Thanks in advance! A lot!

Comment: Stack Views are great, but not always suited for the task. It's not quite clear what you're trying to get... Do you want the two rows of buttons to have equal spacing between Album Title > space > First Row > space > Second Row > space > bottom of view?

Comment: Yes, that's it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple ways to do it... Probably the easiest is to use "spacing views."

Here is the layout with **View as: iPhone 8**

[image]

With this layout, I have 3 Red "spacing views" included in the vertical stack view. They are set equal heights to each other, which ends up giving you equal vertical "spacing." Obviously, you'll change the background color to clear so you don't see them.

Notes:

I gave each button width and height constraints of 44

The Horizontal stack views use:

- Alignment: Fill
- Distribution: Equal Spacing
- Spacing: 0

The Vertical stack view is constrained 20-pts leading / trailing / bottom to the view, and Top is 20-pts from the Bottom of the Label... with:

- Alignment: Fill
- Distribution: Fill
- Spacing: 0

Here is the *exact same* layout with **View as: iPhone 4s** so you can see that it sizes itself as desired, without any changes:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for such a quick response. I was hoping it was something I was missing with StackViews but this is a great workaround.